# How to run sqoop and spark streaming jobs together

Tags: spark-streaming, sqoop

I have a problem with sqoop and spark streaming jobs running together.
When i start spark streaming job and sqoop , the sqoop job stay on "accepted" mode and can't start. However,after killing spark job ,the sqoop job can run properly .
I really dont know what is the problem .

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] of your problem. Otherwise, we won't be able to help.

Comment: If your Spark job eats up **all** the resources available on the cluster, then YARN has no choice but to leave new executions in the queue, with "accepted" status. Open the YARN UI when the Spark job is running and check how much RAM is used / available.